# How to pass method to this.props.children in REACT NATIVE?

Tags: react-native

I need to pass a method from parent to child component via {this.props.children} in react native.

i tried

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { lang: "en" })}
```

but it just giving an error. any idea on how to do this in react native ?

Comment: any reason you want to go this way and not send a method as a prop directly to the component?

Comment: Im creating a custom component that wraps other components. so i need to create a method that i can pass to all children

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function ComponentA(props){
  return(
    <View style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
       {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

---

```
<ComponentA>
  <Text>THIS TEXT WILL HAVE A RED BACKGROUND</Text>
</ComponentA>
```